# Proper place to declare multiple dialog components

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I have a 8 custom Modals that will be called in different places within my app. I currently have them inside the app.component.html like so:

```
<agc class="app-content" [rows]="'auto 1fr'" [height]="'100%'" [pad]="15">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-create-batch #CreateBatch></app-create-batch>
  <app-create-import #CreateImport></app-create-import>
  <app-create-import-newline #CreateImportNewLine></app-create-import-newline>
  <app-export-data #ExportData></app-export-data>
  <app-sales-transaction #SalesTransaction></app-sales-transaction>
  <!-- <app-create-part #CreatePart></app-create-part> -->
  <app-import-export #ImportExport></app-import-export>
  <app-create-claim #CreateClaim></app-create-claim>
  <app-claim-details #ClaimDetails></app-claim-details>
</agc>
```

I didn't realize when putting them here that each dialog would be initialized during start up. Can I get some suggestions on the proper place to put components like Modals that can/will be called on different pages and preferably without having to load each one at startup?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid loading all of them at start up when you place them in the module files of the respective components, where they are opened from. Means import them in those components where you need these modals.

Even more fancier would be if you create lazy loaded child routes and then just call the route to open the dialogs...

Comment: Thank you @gsa.interactive  for the reply. So what you are saying is it is perfectly within standards to create a component that would be the container, a DialogManager for instance and I can use that to kick off the dialogs? One thing I struggle with in Angular is that I research and see tons of examples but everyone seems to do it differently, I can't find any real Standards on how certain scenario's should be done. My forte is c# so im 5 months new to Angular. Just some background - thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I would recommend to do it like or better "with" Angular Material: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api To do it from scratch would end up having with a DialogService that manages content-embedding, show/hide and removing of the dialog. Yes, its CSS styles for the background, the keyboard "esc" i.e... etc.